# Fundamental group of $(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^*)\cup\{(-1,0),(1,0)\}$.

Tags: algebraic-topology

What is the fundamental group of $$X=(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^*)\cup\{(-1,0),(1,0)\}=\{(x,y):y\not=0\}\cup \{(-1,0),(1,0)\}$$?

I'm guessing intuitively that the $X$ deformation retracts to $S^1$ but I'm not so sure.

EDIT: If I define $f:X\to S^1$ by $f(x)=\frac{x}{\|x\|}$, is this a retraction? If that is the case then $\pi_1(X)=\mathbb{Z}$ right?

Comment: What is $\mathbb R^*$?

Comment: Have you tried anything? What's your knowledge about computing fundamental groups?

Comment: @Aweygan Reals without $0$, presumably.

Comment: Try drawing what this set looks like. That gives you a pretty good idea of what the fundamental group is if you just start drawing loops.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Yeah that makes perfect sense.

Comment: @DonAntonio fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ deformation retracts to $S^1$: the map $F:[0,1]\times\mathbb R^2\setminus\{0\}\to S^1$ given by 
$$F(t,x)=\frac{x}{(1-t)+t\|x\|}$$
is such a deformation retraction.

Using this, can you build a deformation retraction from $X$ to $S^1$?

Comment: What if I define $f:X\to S^1$ by $f(x)=x/|x|$. Is it a retraction?

Comment: Yes it is, but if you want isomorphisms of fundamental groups you need a deformation retraction (retractions only give that the inclusion $j:S^1\to X$ is injective).